# tkinter GUI with multiple independent GUI files

Tags: python, tkinter

I've currently got a tkinter app with one window and lots of buttons on it.

As just a snippet, the code is approximately:

```
import tkinter as tk

def openWindow():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.tk()

~ ~ ~ ~

root.mainloop()
```

It is likely that the window generated with the openWindow() function is going to be quite a complicated window alongside my main program. Instead of having one very large python file, I'd prefer it if I had another separate python file which can be opened independently, or imported into my main program and opened when clicking the appropriate button.

How exactly would I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating separate classes for major areas of the GUI.

Lets say you have a Label, Entry and a Button widgets that act like a file select widget, when you click on the button, it opens a dialog to select a file, the selected file path is then shown in the Entry field.
All of this code can exist together and it defines the behavior and appearance of all the elements of the widget.

This could be implemented as a standalone widget as shown below.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class FileSelect(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,label="",**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.configure(**kw)
        self.file = StringVar()

        self.Label = Label(self, text=label)
        self.Label.config(width=10,anchor=E)
        self.filenamebox = Entry(self,text=self.file)
        self.filenamebox.config(width=50)
        self.btnBrowse = Button(self,text='Browse',command=self.browse_file)
        self.btnBrowse.config(width=10)
        self.Label.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=5,sticky=E)
        self.filenamebox.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=5)
        self.btnBrowse.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=5,padx=5)

    def browse_file(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('All File','*.*')])
        self.file.set(filename)

    def get_filename(self):
        return self.file.get()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Example Widget")

    FileSelect(root,label="My File").grid()    
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

We could also include this functionality in a larger section of GUI code.

```
from otherFile import FileSelect
....
fileSelect = FileSelect(root,label="Select New File")
fileSelect.grid()
```

(otherFile is the name of the python file containing the FileSelect widget)
Using this method, you can create smaller sections of code for your GUI in separate code file and build them up in to a more complicate example.

If your have sections of code that perform "non-gui" functions, reading a file for example, put these in to separate functions or classes that you can import in to your main code.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That's perfect

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

1. Try to seperate your "business logics" into classes and modules and put those into one or more `.py` files.  One way to make sure your business modules are *pure* is **not** to `import tkinter` in them.
2. Try to put all your UI in classes and modules and keep them free of business logic. Scan your codes for any lines that involve computations and operations and ask yourself if those lines of code should be moved over to a class as mentioned.
3. To keep each UI file size under manage, group related widgets into your own subclass of `tk.frame`. This also allow you to reuse those code in future projects.

I had GUI-phobia before, but after learning and coding in `tk` and `ttk` for couple weeks I managed to create a superwidget that is practically reused in two unrelated projects.